# Is per-app language settings an iOS 13 only feature?

Tags: ios, localization, settings, ios13, ios14

A few months ago I read [this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=u2cfuj88) and discovered that on iOS 13 we could select the app's language directly from the Settings app.
Now that iOS 14 beta 6 is installed on a test iPhone, the "Preferred language" section is no longer present.
Is the feature removed in iOS 14 or some bug of the beta ? It doesn't seem to be related to whether the app is built using the iOS 14 SDK as the section is not displayed for Facebook from the App Store.

Answer (score 7):

If a "per app language setting" via the Settings app is not accessible in the iOS 14 simulator, *then some second language for the device in Setting > General > Language & Region needs to be added.* After any second language is added *at the device level*, then all language choices for the app will be visible in the Settings > Some Example App > Preferred Language section.

I've not found any documentation as to why this hide-then-show behavior happens.

Comment: Thanks! Also notable- it doesn't matter what the language is, if there is only one language configured in the Language and Region settings then preferred language will not be available in the app-specific settings. That is to say, even if the one language is _not_ one that is supported by the app, the setting is still not available.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. From what I understood sometimes the simulator just lags and doesn't show preferred languages.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to add UIPrefersShowingLanguageSettings with value Yes to info.plist. Without this language setting won't appear for users (also applies to simulator) that don't have two languages selected under "Preferred Language" in system settings